# How to unit test a View class

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to write some unit tests for a custom view class.  The class extends EditText.  Its constructor takes a context and and AttributeSet as required arguments.

```
class CustomEditText(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppCompatEditText(context, attrs) {
...
}
```

Since I need a Context, I gave up on making a unit test, and instead tried to make an instrumented test so that I could get access to ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().  However, I still need an AttributeSet.  AttributeSet is an interface.  It's not clear to me which classes implement this interface, or how I'll need to initialize it so that I can get an instance of the view class.

How can I create an isolated instance of this class so I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I create an isolated instance of this class so I can test it?

Either use a [single-arg constructor that just takes a Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatEditText.html#AppCompatEditText(android.content.Context)) or
use [LayoutInflater.from(context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#from(android.content.Context)) then [inflate(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) to load your view from a test XML file (which would create the `AttributeSet` for you).

Hope that helps!